# Hyper client with tokio File stuck at write()

Tags: asynchronous, rust, deadlock, rust-tokio, hyper

I am trying to do a full-async download attempt.

The download works fine so far.

Using std::fs::File it works fine but I wanted to try tokios File to make the code fully async.

If I just download the file and let the data vanish, it works. But when I use tokio::fs::File to write async the data to disk, the download gets stuck at random locations. Sometimes at 1.1MB, mostly at ~1.6MB. Total is ~9MB.

My test URL is https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.5/cmake-3.20.5.tar.gz

The last output I get is the debug!("Received...") line.

The nearly complete output is:

```
DEBUG: Temp File: /tmp/26392_1625868800106141_ZhWUtnaD.tmp

DEBUG: add_pem_file processed 133 valid and 0 invalid certs
DEBUG: No cached session for DNSNameRef("github.com")
DEBUG: Not resuming any session
DEBUG: Using ciphersuite TLS13_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
DEBUG: Not resuming
DEBUG: TLS1.3 encrypted extensions: [ServerNameAck, Protocols([PayloadU8([104, 50])])]
DEBUG: ALPN protocol is Some(b"h2")
DEBUG: Ticket saved
DEBUG: Ticket saved
DEBUG: Status: 302 Found
[...]
DEBUG: content-length: 621
DEBUG: Sending warning alert CloseNotify

DEBUG: add_pem_file processed 133 valid and 0 invalid certs
DEBUG: No cached session for DNSNameRef("github-releases.githubusercontent.com")
DEBUG: Not resuming any session
DEBUG: Using ciphersuite TLS13_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
DEBUG: Not resuming
DEBUG: TLS1.3 encrypted extensions: [ServerNameAck, Protocols([PayloadU8([104, 50])])]
DEBUG: ALPN protocol is Some(b"h2")
DEBUG: Ticket saved
DEBUG: Status: 200 OK
[...]
DEBUG: content-length: 9441947

DEBUG: Received 16384 bytes (16384 total)
DEBUG: Written 16384 bytes (16384 total)
DEBUG: Received 9290 bytes (25674 total)
DEBUG: Written 9290 bytes (25674 total)
DEBUG: Received 16384 bytes (42058 total)
DEBUG: Written 16384 bytes (42058 total)
[...]
DEBUG: Received 8460 bytes (1192010 total)
DEBUG: Written 8460 bytes (1192010 total)
DEBUG: Received 8948 bytes (1200958 total)
DEBUG: Written 8948 bytes (1200958 total)
DEBUG: Received 8460 bytes (1209418 total)
DEBUG: Written 8460 bytes (1209418 total)
DEBUG: Received 8948 bytes (1218366 total)
[PROCESS STUCK HERE]
```

It feels like there is a deadlock or something that is blocking the write. But I can't find out whats wrong. Why does this get stuck?

Code:

```
async fn download_http<P: AsRef<Path>>(url: &Url, localpath: P) -> MyResult<()> {
    let mut uri = hyper::Uri::from_str(url.as_str())?;

    let mut total_read: usize = 0;
    let mut total_written: usize = 0;
    let mut localfile = File::create(localpath).await?;

    // Redirection Limit
    for i in 0..10 {
        let https = HttpsConnector::with_native_roots();
        let client = Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(https);
        let mut resp = client.get(uri.clone()).await?;

        let status = resp.status();
        let header = resp.headers();

        debug!("Status: {}", status);
        for (key, value) in resp.headers() {
            debug!("HEADER {}: {}", key, value.to_str().unwrap());
        }

        if status.is_success() {
            // tokio::io::copy(&mut resp.body_mut().data(), &mut localfile).await?;

            let expected_size = header.get("content-length").map(|v| v.to_str().unwrap().parse::<usize>().unwrap());
            
            while let Some(next) = resp.data().await {
                let mut chunk = next?;
            
                let num_bytes = chunk.len();
                total_read = total_read + num_bytes;
                debug!("Received {} bytes ({} total)", num_bytes, total_read);
            
                // localfile.write_all(&chunk).await?;
                let written = localfile.write(&chunk).await?;
                total_written = total_written + written;
                debug!("Written {} bytes ({} total)", written, total_written);
            
                if total_read != total_written {
                    error!("Could not write all data!");
                }
            
                if expected_size.is_some() && total_read.eq(&expected_size.unwrap()) {
                    return Ok(());
                }
            }

            return Ok(());
        } else if status.is_redirection() {
            let location = header.get("location").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

            uri = hyper::Uri::from_str(location)?;
        } else {
            let uri_str = uri.to_string();

            return Err(MyError::CustomError(CustomError::from_string(format!("HTTP responded with status {}: {}", status, uri_str))))
        }
    }

    Err(MyError::CustomError(CustomError::from_string(format!("HTTP too many redirections"))))
}
```

Crates (incomplete, relevant only):

```
futures = "0.3"
futures-cpupool = "0.1"
hyper = { version = "0.14", features = ["full"] }
hyper-rustls = "0.22"
rustls = "0.19"
tokio = { version = "1.6", features = ["full"] }
url = "2.2"
```

As you can see the download loop matches example code of the Hyper documentation.

I added the tokio::fs::File writing part

I added debug information (mostly byte sizes) to find out whats going on and where.

The comments are the ideal way: Using write_all or if possible io::copy.

But I can't manage to get it working without getting stuck.

Could you please give me an advice where my mistake is?

Thank you very much

Comment: FYI: when async operations get stuck, sometimes the debug output gets stuck too with stuff still in the buffer.  Not sure if that's your problem, but wanted to drop in a comment and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Ultrasaurus for mentioning this. My logger implementation for the log create has implemented fn flush(&self) as stdout().flush().unwrap(). Is that enough? Commenting out that line does not make a difference so I assume the buffer is flushed.

Comment: I also tried flushing after every log output, no difference.

Comment: Please condense your testcase into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That will increase the chance that someone will have a closer look by a lot.

Comment: You definitely need `localfile.write_all` here. Otherwise the `.write` might only write a part of the data you read, and you drop the remaining data. Does that change help?
I guess since your program never seems to finish the `.write` in any case, it might not?

Comment: @Matthias247 There is a write_all in one of the comments. This was my original line which did not work and did also freeze the program. So It got stuck there, too. That's the whole reason why I tried write() and wrote a whole bunch of debugging code around to figure out why it's not working. The write() call always writes the whole buffer as the output shows. I know that write() might not be able to write everything but it looks like in this case it does always. If it is not writing everything the code would write an error message so I would knew I messed up. You get my idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @HHK in the comments above.

He recommended to build a minimal, reproducible example. While doing that, the example worked fine.

So I iteratively added the code from the original project around it.

The last step I added was a relic I did not remove when making the project async and learning about async.

I had a futures::block_on call within an async function calling an async function which resulted in blocking the whole program randomly.

So I should have made a full working piece of code before posting which would have lead me to the original problem an saved me a lot of headache.

For the future reader:

```
futures = "0.3"
hyper = { version = "0.14", features = ["full"] }
hyper-rustls = "0.22"
rustls = "0.19"
log = "0.4"
tokio = { version = "1.6", features = ["full"] }
url = "2.2"
```

Code:

```
use std::io::{stderr, stdout, Write};
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::str::FromStr;

use futures::executor::block_on;
use hyper::body::HttpBody;
use hyper::Client;
use hyper_rustls::HttpsConnector;
use log::{debug, error, LevelFilter, Log, Metadata, Record};
use tokio::fs::File;
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
use url::Url;

async fn download_http<P: AsRef<Path>>(url: &Url, localpath: P) -> Result<(), ()> {
    let mut uri = hyper::Uri::from_str(url.as_str()).unwrap();

    let mut total_read: usize = 0;
    let mut total_written: usize = 0;
    let mut localfile = File::create(localpath).await.unwrap();

    // Redirection Limit
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let https = HttpsConnector::with_native_roots();
        let client = Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(https);
        let mut resp = client.get(uri.clone()).await.unwrap();

        let status = resp.status();
        let header = resp.headers();

        debug!("Status: {}", status);
        for (key, value) in resp.headers() {
            debug!("HEADER {}: {}", key, value.to_str().unwrap());
        }

        if status.is_success() {
            // tokio::io::copy(&mut resp.body_mut().data(), &mut localfile).await.unwrap();

            let expected_size = header.get("content-length").map(|v| v.to_str().unwrap().parse::<usize>().unwrap());

            while let Some(next) = resp.data().await {
                let chunk = next.unwrap();

                let num_bytes = chunk.len();
                total_read = total_read + num_bytes;
                debug!("Received {} bytes ({} total)", num_bytes, total_read);

                // localfile.write_all(&chunk).await.unwrap();
                let written = localfile.write(&chunk).await.unwrap();
                total_written = total_written + written;
                debug!("Written {} bytes ({} total)", written, total_written);

                if total_read != total_written {
                    error!("Could not write all data!");
                }

                if expected_size.is_some() && total_read.eq(&expected_size.unwrap()) {
                    return Ok(());
                }
            }

            return Ok(());
        } else if status.is_redirection() {
            let location = header.get("location").unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

            uri = hyper::Uri::from_str(location).unwrap();
        } else {
            return Err(());
        }
    }

    return Err(());
}


struct Logger;

impl Log for Logger {
    fn enabled(&self, _: &Metadata) -> bool {
        true
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &Record) {
        eprintln!("{}: {}", record.level().as_str().to_uppercase(), record.args());
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
        stderr().flush().unwrap();
    }

    fn flush(&self) {
        stdout().flush().unwrap();
        stderr().flush().unwrap();
    }
}

static LOGGER: Logger = Logger;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    log::set_logger(&LOGGER).map(move |()| log::set_max_level(LevelFilter::Debug)).unwrap();

    let url = Url::parse("https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.20.5/cmake-3.20.5.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let localfile = PathBuf::from("/tmp/cmake-3.20.5.tar.gz");

    block_on(download_http(&url, &localfile)).unwrap();
    // download_http(&url, &localfile).await.unwrap();
}
```

Switching between block_on and not using it makes the difference.

Now I can switch back to using write_all and remove my debugging code.